# PHP Use returned value of a function in another Function

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink

The Following code is checking for links within a page and then trying to process those links and check if they work or not, by returning a header code.
I basically need to use the returned value $links of the first function in the second one. is it possible?

here is my code

```
function checkPage ($content){ 
   $textLen = strlen($content);  
   $links = array (); 
   if ( $textLen > 5){ 
      $startPos = 0; 
      $valid = true; 

      while ($valid){ 
         $spos  = strpos($content,'<a ',$startPos); 
         if ($spos < $startPos) $valid = false; 
         $spos     = strpos($content,'href',$spos); 
         $spos     = strpos($content,'"',$spos)+1; 
         $epos     = strpos($content,'"',$spos); 
         $startPos = $epos; 
         $link = substr($content,$spos,$epos-$spos); 
         if (strpos($link,'https://') !== false) $links[] = $link;
         if (strpos($link,'http://') !== false) $links[] = $link;
      } 
   } 
  return **$links**; 
};

print_r(checkPage($content));

foreach ($links as &$link ) {
$ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   $headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
   if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}   
   curl_close($ch);
   echo $link." returns code ".$headers['http_code']."<br />";  
};
```

Comment: `return **$links**;`? Do you mean that you simply want to store the value from the `checkPage()` function? This is PHP101... `$links = checkPage($content);`.

Comment: Do you just need `$links = checkPage($content);` ? That looks to be missing from your code, but that's very basic PHP considering what you already have.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to copy the variable "content" that contain a piece of HTML markup. Return **$links**; should be displayed without the asterisks as I tried to bold the word on the page editor here.

Comment: I would highly recommend going through some basic PHP-tutorials

Answer (score 2):

You're printing the returned value, but then ignoring it after that:

```
print_r(checkPage($content));
```

Store the returned value in a variable.  It *doesn't need* to be the same variable name.  And in this case it probably shouldn't be the same variable name to keep the concept clear.  So something like this:

```
$returnedLinks = checkPage($content);
print_r($returnedLinks);

foreach ($returnedLinks as $link ) {
    // do something with $link
}
```

Returning a value from a function doesn't make *the variable itself* available outside the function.  It just means that when you call the function then that function call evaluates to a result, just as if you defined that result in-line instead of calling a function.  You just need to store that result in a variable to use it, just like any other value.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new around coding.